# Defined `tryCatch` function operator incorrect return

Tags: r, try-catch

I want to define a function operator that will get a plot as input and in case it produces an error it should return another plot.
My try:

```
handle_plot_error <- function(f) {
    wrapper <- function(...) {
        tryCatch(
            {
                f(...)
            },
            error = function(e) {
                hist(1:3)
            }
        )
    }
    
    wrapper
}
```

But when I try:

```
handle_plot_error(plot(1,1))
```

it returns:

```
function(...) {
        tryCatch(
            {
                return(f(...))
            },
            error = function(e) {
                return(hist(1:3))
            }
        )
    }
<bytecode: 0x7ff29dc38668>
<environment: 0x7ff29d9fab00>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `wrapper` ? You may try :

```
handle_plot_error <- function(f) {
    tryCatch(
      {
        f
      },
      error = function(e) {
        hist(1:3)
      }
    )
}
```

where :

```
#No error plot
handle_plot_error(plot(1, 1)) #returns
```

[image]

and

```
#Error plot
handle_plot_error(plot(1:5, a = 2)) #returns
```

[image]

Comment: I tried to copy the form from Python decorator definitions. I see I overcomplicated thingies, thanks!

Comment: do you have any idea why `handle_plot_error` function is not working for ggplot2 facets?

Comment: It is working for me when I put `error = function(e) {     ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~cyl)  }`. Do you meant that or something else?

Comment: I mean like this:
```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

foo <- function(df) {
    df %>% 
        ggplot(aes(cyl, mpg)) + 
        geom_line() + 
        facet_grid(~am)
}

handle_plot_error(foo(tibble())) # simulates empty df as can happen in real scenario
```

Comment: The error comes in the function `foo` itself before going to `handle_plot_error` function. `foo(tibble())`

Comment: Do you have any idea how to solve this? I can also open a new question.

Comment: Can you use the same `tryCatch` approach in the `foo` function? Yeah..I guess it is better to ask this as a new question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229190/discussion-between-mihagazvoda-and-ronak-shah).